# Number of compositions of $n$ where each part is at least $m$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> How many compositions of $n$ are there where each part is at least $m$?

**My attempt:**

So far I have found the generating function and have that the desired number of compositions is
$$
[x^{n}]\frac{1-x}{1-x-x^{m}}.
$$

But I am unsure how to proceed, I have made a few attempts to transform this (for example using the geometric series or through rewriting), perhaps there is a simple way to do this and I am overlooking it. Does anybody have any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I have summarized how I've obtained the previous expression, kindly mention if you notice any mistakes. Note that $\Phi_{N\geq m} = \left(\sum_{i \geq m} x^{i}\right) = \left(\sum_{i \geq 0} x^{i+m}\right)$

$$\Phi_{\cup_{k\geq 0}N_{\geq m}^{k}}(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0}(\Phi_{N\geq m}(x))^{k} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\left(\sum_{i\geq 0} x^{i+m}\right)^{k} = \sum_{k\geq 0}\left(x^{m}\sum_{i\geq 0} x^{i}\right)^{k}$$
$$
= \sum_{k\geq 0}(x^{m}(1-x)^{-1})^{k} = \frac{1}{1-x^{m}(1-x)^{-1}} = \frac{1-x}{1-x-x^{m}}
$$

Comment: did you think $$(x^m)/(1-x)=x^m+x^{m+1}+.....$$

Comment: Are you sure you have the right generating function? I'm getting something different. Please elaborate how you got the said function.

Comment: @DS I have added some of the work I did to arrive at that expression, please let me know if you notice any errors. Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you use the expansion of $(1-x)^{-k}$ in the last line?

Comment: @DS I had used this in a similar problem, perhaps using the expansion of $(1-x)^{-k}$ is simpler. If have tried using that as well, would the desired coefficient then be $\binom{k+n-mk-1}{n-mk}$?

Comment: @JLGL it would be summed over all $k\ge 1$. I think I have seen a closed form for this, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish I have tried using this as well, but I don't know how to use what you gave. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like this has no closed form for $m>2$. What is the source of the question?

Comment: @JLGL well, your answer is totally correct, but I did not understand for which step you want help. You can use wolfram alpha for calculating the coeffiient of $x^n$

Comment: @NotaSalmonFish Thank you, I am having trouble simplifying the expression for the coefficient I originally gave, algebraically that is. Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed? I assume it is a tedious process.

Answer (score 2):

We obtain for $m,n\geq 2$ using the geometric series expansion
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[x^n]}&\color{blue}{\frac{1-x}{1-x-x^m}}=[x^n]\frac{1-x}{1-x\left(1+x^{m-1}\right)}\\
&=[x^n](1-x)\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}x^q\left(1+x^{m-1}\right)^q\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^n[x^{n-q}]\left(1+x^{m-1}\right)^q(1-x)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^n[x^{n-q}]\sum_{j=0}^q\binom{q}{j}x^{(m-1)j}(1-x)\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^n[x^{q}]\sum_{j=0}^{n-q}\binom{n-q}{j}x^{(m-1)j}(1-x)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m-1}\right\rfloor}
[x^{(m-1)q}]\sum_{j=0}^{n-(m-1)q}\binom{n-(m-1)q}{j}x^{(m-1)j}(1-x)\tag{4}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{m-1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-(m-1)q}{q}
-\sum_{q=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{m-1}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-1-(m-1)q}{q}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$. We also set the upper limit of the series to $n$ since other terms do not contribute to $[x^n]$.
- In (2) we make a binomial expansion.
- In (3) we change the order of summation $q\to n-q$.
- In (4) we note the index $j$ needs to be a multiple of $m-1$ for coefficient selection.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^{(m-1)q}$. We take the factor $(1-x)$ into account by subtracting the sum from the same sum, but replacing $n$ with $n-1$.